# Applying global style across multiple assemblies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, theming

My application is composed from quite a few assemblies ("plug-ins") that are loaded by a core executable assembly (which doesn't contain any controls or windows on it own). Now I want to apply styles to controls (such as Menus/ContextMenus, ToolBar(Tray)s etc.) from the central assembly's Application.Resources styles (possibly with the option of users being able to choose from several themes).

I got it to work with named styles (`x:Key="StyleName"`, invoked by `DynamicResource`, `StaticResource` wouldn't work), but the prospect of adding the `Style="{DynamicResource ...}"` to every control in every assembly scares me quire a little bit. But the control-wide styles with `TargetType="{x:Type TypeName}"` won't work no matter what I do.

**How can I style all the controls en masse from one central assembly?**

Thanks for help.

Comment: So adding these Styles to App.xaml gives you no effect what so ever?

Comment: Yes, <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToolbarTray}"><Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink" /></Style> doesn't do anything.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. Just to be sure this is not the issue, ToolbarTray is a typo right? Should be ToolBarTray :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [this great article on WPF skinning](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/SkinningInWPF.aspx) might help point you in the right direction?

In the intro, he highlights the "three pillars" for skinning/theming and how hierarchical resources can be leveraged.

Though I do fear (without certainty) that you might still need to change your static resources to dynamic ones.

Comment: The article led to to a solution: I had the styles all specified inside a ResourceDictionary inside MergedDcitionaries property of the main ResourceDictionary tag together with a link to a skin for one UsercCntrol I use. I moved the syles into the main Resource Dictionary and it suddenly works. I didn't know ResourceDictionary can have both MergedDictionaries and its own resources, so I put the local resources in a merged dictionary. Thanks for the link, that truly is an excellent article.